# Open HTML link from devexpress's ASPxSpreadsheet

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

As indicated in the title, I would like to open a HTML link, but I'm uncertain if what I'm currently doing is correct. I'm using a hyperlink, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
CellRange nameFileCellRange = secondWorksheet.Cells["C7"];
nameFileCellRange.Value = "Drawing: " + fileName;

Hyperlink nameFileHyperlink = secondWorksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(nameFileCellRange, "javascript:openFile(" + filename + ")", true, filename);
nameFileHyperlink.TooltipText = "open";
```

And here's the JavaScript function:

```
function openFile(fileName) {
    console.log("hi");
    var _url = "./TraceabilityNP.aspx?id=" + encodeURIComponent(fileName);
    var _name = "VIEWFILE";
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;

    var x = window.open(_url, _name, "width=" + w + ", height=" + h);
    x.focus();
}
```

Could you please let me know what might be going wrong? Alternatively, are there any other approaches I could try?

Comment: The data being populated in the spreadsheet originates directly from a SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: How did the `a` tag was rendered in the browser? If you inspect it and copy outer html

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, I use the ASPxSpreadsheet interface, how do I see a label?

Comment: Can you provide more server code rather than those 4 lines ?

Comment: In Google Chrome, Right click > inspect, in the window that opens, right click copy outer html
https://prnt.sc/aurwXXGL_EKO
https://prnt.sc/wadKMJA6MOlC

Comment: "seem to be working for me" is not very helpful. What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? Do you get console errors? Does your `console.log` display anything.

Comment: @Wonderweis check the Answer with a solution, i got it working on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take into account the following information from official Devexpress site:

[ASPxSpreadsheet does not allow opening files using URL](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t533383/aspxspreadsheet-how-to-open-a-file-from-url)

The supported methods are listed here (notice NO Url):

[ASPxSpreadsheet.Open Method](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/devexpress.web.aspxspreadsheet.aspxspreadsheet.open.overloads)

**UPDATE 1 (Unique Cell):**
Since you can use devex clientsideevents (pure javascript) what you need to do are two things:

**1. On the server side (notice the dummy URI)**

```
        Cell cell = worksheet1.Cells["B4"]; //This is for one cell you can use CellRange for N cells.
        var fileUrl = "https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-spreadsheetcontrol-api-part1/blob/23.1.2%2B/Readme.md";
        worksheet1.Hyperlinks.Add(cell, fileUrl, true, "DevExpress Spreadsheet Repo");
```

**2. On the client**

Use the HyperlinkClick client side event for the worksheet and define it as follows(notice im using a dummy URI previously loaded on #1):

```
  <ClientSideEvents 
            HyperlinkClick="function(s, e) {             
            var _url=e.targetUri;
            var _name = 'VIEWFILE';
            var w = 600;
            var h = 400;                                    
            var x= window.open(_url,_name,'width=' + w + ',height=' + h); 
            x.focus();            
            e.handled = true;           
            }"
        />
```

**UPDATE 2 (Cell Range):**

**1. On the server side (notice the dummy URI)**

```
CellRange nameFileCellRange = secondWorksheet.Range["C7"]; //Notice you can specify a range of cells ir ["C7:C10"]
        string url= "https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-spreadsheetcontrol-api-part1/blob/23.1.2%2B/Readme.md";
        nameFileCellRange.Value = "Drawing: " + url;
        Hyperlink nameFileHyperlink = secondWorksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(nameFileCellRange, url, true, nameFileCellRange.Value.ToString());
        nameFileHyperlink.TooltipText = "open";
```

**2. On the client (actually is the same code as first update with single cell)**

Use the HyperlinkClick client side event for the worksheet and define it as follows(notice im using a dummy URI previously loaded on #1):

```
<ClientSideEvents 
    HyperlinkClick="function(s, e) {                         
    var _url = e.targetUri;            
    var _name = 'VIEWFILE';
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;                                    
    var x= window.open(_url,_name,'width=' + w + ',height=' + h); 
    x.focus();            
    e.handled = true;           
    }"
/>
```

Comment: This is functioning correctly; however, within my code, I aim to utilize the hyperlink to open a page of my own, where I can assign the parameter 'fileName'. I would like to determine if I am on the right track or if there is an alternative approach that I have not yet discovered, unfortunately

Comment: why not use the targeturi as a file path ?

Comment: Hello, here's the code:

`spreadsheet.ClientSideEvents.HyperlinkClick = $"onLinkClick('{id}')";
Hyperlink cellHyperlink = secondWorksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(nameFileCellRange, id, false, name);cellHyperlink.TooltipText = "OpenFile";` 


js:
`function onLinkClick(id) {
    var _url = "sample" + id;
    var _name = "file";
    var w = 600;
    var h = 400;

var x= window.open(_url,_name,'width=' + w + ',height=' + h); 
x.focus(); 
}`
However, I have a question. Why do all the hyperlink windows open when I run the spreadsheet?

Comment: add e.handled= true; at the end of your code Does it work ?

Comment: thanks, it really worked, the code is fine